# Mapping response.body to model class

Tags: json, flutter, dart, decode

I'm trying to map response to model class and then show all elements one by one, so that user can scroll down. Response goes like that:

```
{"items":[{"id":"bd9acd37-5c91-47cb-a71e-0e43fb2f7882","imageUrl":"","title":"fak hez as","city":"Gdansk"},{"id":"210ad8c8-d279-4c38-845c-34c772cfec21","imageUrl":"","title":"Some random title :)","city":"Warsaw"}],"total":2,"pageNumber":1}
```

And my model which I have generated with https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/12562-jsontodart-json-to-dart-

```
class Advertisement {
  List<Items>? _items;
  int? _total;
  int? _pageNumber;

  List<Items>? get items => _items;

  int? get total => _total;

  int? get pageNumber => _pageNumber;

  Advertisement({List<Items>? items, int? total, int? pageNumber}) {
    _items = items;
    _total = total;
    _pageNumber = pageNumber;
  }

  Advertisement.fromJson(dynamic json) {
    if (json["items"] != null) {
      _items = [];
      json["items"].forEach((v) {
        _items?.add(Items.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
    _total = json["total"];
    _pageNumber = json["pageNumber"];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    var map = <String, dynamic>{};
    if (_items != null) {
      map["items"] = _items?.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    map["total"] = _total;
    map["pageNumber"] = _pageNumber;
    return map;
  }
}

/// id : "bd9acd37-5c91-47cb-a71e-0e43fb2f7882"
/// imageUrl : ""
/// title : "fak hez as"
/// city : "Gdansk"

class Items {
  String? _id;
  String? _imageUrl;
  String? _title;
  String? _city;

  String? get id => _id;

  String? get imageUrl => _imageUrl;

  String? get title => _title;

  String? get city => _city;

  Items({String? id, String? imageUrl, String? title, String? city}) {
    _id = id;
    _imageUrl = imageUrl;
    _title = title;
    _city = city;
  }

  Items.fromJson(dynamic json) {
    _id = json["id"];
    _imageUrl = json["imageUrl"];
    _title = json["title"];
    _city = json["city"];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    var map = <String, dynamic>{};
    map["id"] = _id;
    map["imageUrl"] = _imageUrl;
    map["title"] = _title;
    map["city"] = _city;
    return map;
  }
}
```

My screen:

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:.../constants/AppConstants.dart';
import 'package:.../ui/pages/home/page/Advertisement.dart';
import 'package:.../util/HttpActions.dart';

import 'BottomAppBar.dart';
import 'FAB.dart';
import 'Advertisement.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String jwt;

  const HomePage(this.jwt);

  @override
  _HomePage createState() => _HomePage();

  factory HomePage.fromBase64(String jwt) => HomePage(jwt);
}

class _HomePage extends State<HomePage> {
  late final String jwt;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    jwt = widget.jwt;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Scaffold(
        body: Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: const Color(0xFEF9F9FC),
          floatingActionButtonLocation:
              FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
          floatingActionButton: buildFAB(),
          bottomNavigationBar: BuildBottomAppBar(),
          body: Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(35.0),
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
            child: Column(
              children: [
                FutureBuilder(
                  future: fetchAdvertisements(),
                  builder: (context, snapshot) => snapshot.hasData
                      ? Text("")
                      : snapshot.hasError
                          ? Text("An error occurred")
                          : CircularProgressIndicator(),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );

  Future<List<Advertisement>?> fetchAdvertisements() async {
    var response = await HttpActions.makeHttpGet(
        {},
        AppConstants.ADVERTISEMENTS_ENDPOINT,
        {HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader: HttpActions.APPLICATION_JSON_HEADER});

    print(response.statusCode);
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      print(response.body);
      final responseList = json.decode(response.body);
      print(responseList);
      List<Advertisement> z = (json.decode(response.body) as List)
          .map((i) => Advertisement.fromJson(i))
          .toList();
      print(z);
      return null;
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to load post');
    }
  }
}
```

Error occurs while executing this line:

```
List<Advertisement> z = (json.decode(response.body) as List)
              .map((i) => Advertisement.fromJson(i))
              .toList();
```

it does not map to this List

While debugging I get:

[image: result of executing of above method]

What I'm making wrong? Is there something wrong with model class?

Answer (score 0):

One more mistake that you are making with your code, You are calling fetchAdvertisement() method inside a build(BuildContext context). This means everytime build() method gets called. It will call  fetchAdvertisement() this as well.

```
 Column(
              children: [
                FutureBuilder(
                  future: fetchAdvertisements(),
                  builder: (context, snapshot) => snapshot.hasData
                      ? Text("")
                      : snapshot.hasError
                          ? Text("An error occurred")
                          : CircularProgressIndicator(),
                ),
              ],
            ),
```

To avoid such an issue.

```
   
    late Function _fetchAdvertisements;

    void initState() {
        super.initState();
_fetchAdvertisements = fetchAdvertisements(); }
```

```
       Column(
              children: [
                FutureBuilder(
                  future: _fetchAdvertisements,
                  builder: (context, snapshot) => snapshot.hasData
                      ? Text("")
                      : snapshot.hasError
                          ? Text("An error occurred")
                          : CircularProgressIndicator(),
                ),
              ],
            ),
```

Comment: The argument type 'Function' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Future<Object?>?'.

Comment: Function<Object?>?  _fetchAdvertisements;

Comment: Could you provide whole answer? It does not work.

Comment: Check my complete code sample, This will solve your problem. :) . If that solves your problem. Kindly let me know.

Comment: I was saying about calling fetchAdvertisement() method inside a build(BuildContext context). This code sample in this anwer does not work. What is Function<Object?>? _fetchAdvertisements; I cannot declare sosmething like this.

Comment: Check out my new answer , then let me know :)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot simply parse this with cast `as List`. Because your response isn't even a List.

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "id": "bd9acd37-5c91-47cb-a71e-0e43fb2f7882",
      "imageUrl": "",
      "title": "fak hez as",
      "city": "Gdansk"
    },
    {
      "id": "210ad8c8-d279-4c38-845c-34c772cfec21",
      "imageUrl": "",
      "title": "Pozdrawiam z Łodzi :)",
      "city": "Warsaw"
    }
  ],
  "total": 2,
  "pageNumber": 1
}
```

For this response, you can parse this like this:

```
Advertisement.fromJson(json.decode(response.body))
```

But now you have only one item of `Advertisement`.

If your response were like this, with multiple advertisements:

```
{
  "advertisements": [
    {
      "items": [
        {
          "id": "bd9acd37-5c91-47cb-a71e-0e43fb2f7882",
          "imageUrl": "",
          "title": "fak hez as",
          "city": "Gdansk"
        },
        {
          "id": "212ad8c8-d279-4c38-845c-34c772cfec21",
          "imageUrl": "",
          "title": "Great city!",
          "city": "Łódź"
        }
      ],
      "total": 2,
      "pageNumber": 1
    },
    {
      "items": [
        {
          "id": "bd9acd37-5c91-47cb-a71e-0e43fb2f7882",
          "imageUrl": "",
          "title": "fak hez as",
          "city": "Gdansk"
        },
        {
          "id": "210ad8c8-d279-4c38-845c-34c772cfec21",
          "imageUrl": "",
          "title": "Some random title :)",
          "city": "Warsaw"
        }
      ],
      "total": 2,
      "pageNumber": 1
    }
  ]
}
```

You can parse this simply with this code:

```
List<Advertisement> advertisements = [
      for (final advertisement in json.decode(response2)['advertisements'])
        Advertisement.fromJson(advertisement)
    ];
```

You can learn how to do JSON serialization properly with `JsonSerializable` I recommend you to read this [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/json#creating-model-classes-the-json_serializable-way).

Answer (score 0):

I just copied you responded.body text and showed you a dummy example. Everything will be done in the same way, weather you use an HTTP calls. Always make sure that you know what response is coming.

[image]

```
 class __AppState extends State<_App> {
      @override
      void initState() {
        // TODO: implement initState
        super.initState();
        convertApiResponse();
      }
    
      Future<String> getApiJson() async {
        return '{"items":[{"id":"bd9acd37-5c91-47cb-a71e-0e43fb2f7882","imageUrl":"","title":"fak hez as","city":"Gdansk"},{"id":"210ad8c8-d279-4c38-845c-34c772cfec21","imageUrl":"","title":"Some random title :)","city":"Warsaw"}],"total":2,"pageNumber":1} ';
      }
    
      Future<void> convertApiResponse() async {
        final data = await getApiJson();
        final decodedData = json.decode(data) as Map;
        Advertisement x = Advertisement.fromJson(decodedData);
        x._items!.forEach((element) {
          log("Item-> City: ${element.city}");
          log("Item->ID: ${element.id}");
          log("Item->ImageURL: ${element.imageUrl}");
          log("Item->Title: ${element.title}");
        });
        log("Page Number: ${x.pageNumber}");
        log("Total: ${x.total}");
      }
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(home: Scaffold());
      }
    }
```

Untouched Items.dart

```
class Items {
  String? _id;
  String? _imageUrl;
  String? _title;
  String? _city;

  String? get id => _id;

  String? get imageUrl => _imageUrl;

  String? get title => _title;

  String? get city => _city;

  Items({String? id, String? imageUrl, String? title, String? city}) {
    _id = id;
    _imageUrl = imageUrl;
    _title = title;
    _city = city;
  }

  Items.fromJson(dynamic json) {
    _id = json["id"];
    _imageUrl = json["imageUrl"];
    _title = json["title"];
    _city = json["city"];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    var map = <String, dynamic>{};
    map["id"] = _id;
    map["imageUrl"] = _imageUrl;
    map["title"] = _title;
    map["city"] = _city;
    return map;
  }
}
```

Untouched Advertisement.dart

```
class Advertisement {
  List<Items>? _items;
  int? _total;
  int? _pageNumber;

  List<Items>? get items => _items;

  int? get total => _total;

  int? get pageNumber => _pageNumber;

  Advertisement({List<Items>? items, int? total, int? pageNumber}) {
    _items = items;
    _total = total;
    _pageNumber = pageNumber;
  }

  Advertisement.fromJson(dynamic json) {
    if (json["items"] != null) {
      _items = [];
      json["items"].forEach((v) {
        _items?.add(Items.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
    _total = json["total"];
    _pageNumber = json["pageNumber"];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    var map = <String, dynamic>{};
    if (_items != null) {
      map["items"] = _items?.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    map["total"] = _total;
    map["pageNumber"] = _pageNumber;
    return map;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a picture that resolves your fetchAdvertisements() call on every build

[image]